# How to merge/create new partition using unallocated space left after installing Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, merge

I formatted my computer a few days back and installed Windows 7 first and then Ubuntu alongside. But I noticed that there's about 140 GB of unallocated space, left after the Ubuntu partition.Here's how my partitions look right now:

[image: My partition]

I would love to use that space as a new partition in Windows or atleast merge it with D. So is it at all possible?

Comment: Please tell me what do you want to do with the Unallocated space ?
You want a WIN only partition ? You want to use the 140GB for both WIN and Ubuntu ? you want to merge the 140GB with Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

**I want to use the un-allocated space**

**Case #1** - for both Ubuntu and Windows

Right click on the un-allocated space, create NEW SIMPLE volume

Then on the Pop up window Next->Setup NTFS, Drive Letter etc->Next->Finish

Right Click on the newly created partition, Mark as Active (if not available)
If Ubuntu is atleast 12.04 and up, you should see the new partition under Ubuntu no additional steps needed

**Case #2** - to extend Ubuntu's partition

Please refer to this external link going through Ubuntu's resizing using a Ubuntu Live CD : http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

**Case #3** - to extend Windows partition

If diskmgmt.msc does not allow you to Extend volume when right-click'ing on it, it means windows will not supprt the "merge".

Note: last time i did this via Hirens or Ubuntu's Gparted my Windows partition crashed (due to misalingment etc)